# Symfony will not populate a form with large string after bind()

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I am having issues trying to override the value of a form field after submission.  Currently the form includes a textarea and file upload input, but only one is used.  If the user uploads a file it is parsed into text.  I want to use the data that is parsed from the file as the value for the textare when the page reloads, rather than what was in the text box (empty).  The content can not be determined until after the bind.

What I did was just bind the data again to manually set the value of the textarea after the document was parse.  It works great if I hard code a value for the value, however when I use the full contents of the file, nothing is put in the textarea.  There isn't some sort of length limit or something that could interfere with the population is there?  I have tried short strings and they work fine, but these files are about 4k in length and won't populate in the text area.

Works

```
$this->form->bind(array('text'=>'1234'), $request->getFiles('profile_generate') );
```

Does not work, even though the value text is actually being set.

```
$this->form->bind(array('text'=>$largeString), $request->getFiles('profile_generate') );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIX:
I suppose whatever function that Symfony uses to populate the fields from the bind() values has a problem with non-standard characters.  Unfortunately it does not complain about it or let on to what the issue really is.  After cleaning up the data, it worked fine.

```
$largeString = preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)\x0A]+/',' ', $largeString);
$this->form->bind(array('text'=>$largeString), $request->getFiles('profile_generate') );
```